# typescript open multiple tabs with for loop

Tags: typescript, vue.js

i tried to open a new tab with the following code

```
      window.open("wwww.stackoverflow.com", "_blank");
```

That works great for me but when i have a array with URL´s and tried to open them only the first element opening in a new tab. All loops are executed, but only 1 tab is open.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
      console.log("open tab" + i);
      window.open(urlArray[i], "_blank"); 
     }
```

Any ideas why ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most chromium based web browsers will block multiple pop-ups from opening in succession.

You can allow a certain site to open multiple popups through the settings menu of your browser.

[image]

[More on blocking and allowing pop-ups from google support.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472)

Comment: Thank you that works fine for me. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Whenever pop-ups are blocked a prompt is shown in the top-right of the search bar asking the user to allow pop-ups. You could add a prompt to ask the user accept it.

Alternatively you could try adding a delay to prevent the automatic blocking in the first place.